# Empty folder with .gitkeep not pushed to repository

Tags: git

I have empty folder logs with .gitkeep inside:

```
logs/.gitkeep
```

after i push my code to repository:

```
git add . && git commit -m . --allow-empty && git push origin master
```

logs folder doesn't get pushed (everything else works/get pushed fine).

I'm sure it was working sometime ago, did something changed with git update or i miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High chance that you have `log` directory mentioned in `.gitignore`

PS : `.gitkeep` is not a git feature. It's just tricking git into pushing the directory with dummy file.

Answer (score 1):

Use -f if you really want to add them.

```
git add -f logs/.gitkeep
```